# Django + React -> fetch / axios

Tags: reactjs, django, api

I want fetch data to Django backend from React and request the params in url with
'request.GET.get("",None)' [or alternatives?]. The best case would be a solution for multiple params or in body.
Every tutorial only shows fetch to models, but all references I found for request or create() the parameters in my views.py ( to do other stuff with values in views) did not work.

```
//Form.js
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'+'?name='+name+'/'
axios.post(url, { title: title,
                  value1: value1,
                  value2: value2,
                })
```

I want to scrape the 'name' from url (in next steps I need 'params' from body, too) in my views.py to do further action with the values.

```
#views.py    
def my_view(request, name):
   request_name = request.GET.get("name", None)
```

I think possible problem with the urls referenced param 'name',

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
  path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('api/', views.my_view ),
  path('api/<name>/', views.my_view ),
  #path('api/(?P<name>\d+)/', views.my_view),
  #re_path('api/<name>)/', views.my_view , name='name'),
  #re_path('api/(?P<name>\d+)/', views.my_view , name='name'),
  #path('api/<name>/)', views.my_view , name='name'),
  #re_path(r'^api/<name>/$', views.my_view),
```

because,

---

when I tried:

fetch url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'+name+'/' -> without the '?name='

with this urls.py

```
path('api/<name>/', views.my_view )
```

I can print(name) in views.py  -> results is correct name

```
def my_view(request, name):
   #request_name = request.GET.get("name", None)
   print(name)
```

print(name) does not work when I have '?name=' in url.

Comment: Please take a look at DRF filtering: [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/). What you need are [query parameters](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters).

Good tutorial about [CRUD in Django Rest Framework and React](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/crud-django-rest-framework-react/).

Comment: I know that I still haven't understood a lot. I will still do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'+name+'/'; the usage of ?name is not correct here since you provide the name as a get parameter.
using get parameters makes no sense here. you directly have to call the url.

Another hint: You should generate the url by the following in the django template:

{% url 'name' name %}

Comment: thanks,
I already had this solution, so to speak, and didn't notice it.